# Better way to search for a string in list of tuples

Tags: python

I have written a snippet to find the string in the list of tuples. Just out of curiosity, I would like to know whether it can be improved or not. Any feedback or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

I have the following list

```
  final_artist_filenames = [] 

  files = ['102257.jpg','752232.jpg','32145.jpg','20304.jpg']

  artist_tuples = [('House Manhufe','102257.jpg'), 
                   ('Bernett Newman','75232.jpg'),
                   ('House Manhufe','32145.jpg'),
                   ('Kiri nichol','20304.jpg'),
                   ('Wolfgang', '48876.jpg'),
                   ('Arabesque','63861.jpg'),
                   ('Francis','99442.jpg')]
```

List all tuples whose file name are in list `files`.

so the expected output is

```
[('House Manhufe','102257.jpg'),('Bernett Newman','75232.jpg'),('House Manhufe','32145.jpg'),('Kiri nichol','20304.jpg')]
```

Below is my implementation

```
    final_artist_filenames = [] 

    files = ['102257.jpg','752232.jpg','32145.jpg','20304.jpg']

    artist_tuples = [('House Manhufe','102257.jpg'), 
                   ('Bernett Newman','75232.jpg'),
                   ('House Manhufe','32145.jpg'),
                   ('Kiri nichol','20304.jpg'),
                   ('Wolfgang', '48876.jpg'),
                   ('Arabesque','63861.jpg'),
                   ('Francis','99442.jpg')]


    for filename in files:
        for etuple in artist_tuples:
            if etuple[1] == filename:
               final_artist_filenames.append((artist,etuple[1]))
```

The reason behind requesting for a better version is due to the length of each the list

```
  len(files) = 8000
  len(artist_tuples) = 10000
```

Comment: Try code review instead of stack overflow for things like this. Stack overflow is for debugging and code review is for optimization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think one of the biggest improvements you could make is to use a dictionary. Instead of looping through all of the `artist_tuples` for each filename in `files`, you can just do a single lookup in a dictionary for each of the filenames in `files`. This should speed up your code quite a bit.

I wasn't sure if you have to have the output back into tuples so the first example does that but the other one outputs the results in a dictionary (basically a sub-dictionary of `by_filename` filtered by `files`).

```
In[2]: artist_tuples = [
  ...:     ('House Manhufe','102257.jpg'),
  ...:     ('Bernett Newman','75232.jpg'),
  ...:     ('House Manhufe','32145.jpg'),
  ...:     ('Kiri nichol','20304.jpg'),
  ...:     ('Wolfgang', '48876.jpg'),
  ...:     ('Arabesque','63861.jpg'),
  ...:     ('Francis','99442.jpg')
  ...: ]
In[3]: files = ['102257.jpg','75232.jpg','32145.jpg','20304.jpg']
In[4]: by_filename = {filename: artist for artist, filename in artist_tuples}
In[5]: final_artist_filenames = []
  ...: for filename in files:
  ...:     try:
  ...:         artist = by_filename[filename]
  ...:     except KeyError:
  ...:         pass
  ...:     else:
  ...:         final_artist_filenames.append((artist, filename))
  ...: 
In[6]: final_artist_filenames
Out[6]: 
[('House Manhufe', '102257.jpg'),
 ('Bernett Newman', '75232.jpg'),
 ('House Manhufe', '32145.jpg'),
 ('Kiri nichol', '20304.jpg')]
In[7]: by_filename_only_from_files = {}
  ...: for filename in files:
  ...:     try:
  ...:         artist = by_filename[filename]
  ...:     except KeyError:
  ...:         pass
  ...:     else:
  ...:         by_filename_only_from_files[filename] = artist
  ...: 
In[8]: by_filename_only_from_files
Out[8]: 
{'102257.jpg': 'House Manhufe',
 '20304.jpg': 'Kiri nichol',
 '32145.jpg': 'House Manhufe',
 '75232.jpg': 'Bernett Newman'}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's better, you'll have to try and time both solution, but maybe list comprehension could be faster.

```
[(name, file) for name, file in artist_tuples if file in files]
```

Second solution that could be tested and might be faster is to use numpy arrays instead of list. Maybe even if you have to convert first into a numpy array (`np.asarray`), I think the overall process should be faster.